# Reading and reshaping data in R with multiple delimiters

Tags: r, reshape

I have a big file (2GB) and would like to reshape it as follows

**Input**

```
o1,o1_1,o1_2|a1,1  
o2,o2_1,o2_2|b1,1|b2,1|b3,2  
o3,o3_1,o3_2|c1,1
```

**Expected Output**

```
o1,o1_1,o1_2,a1,1   
o2,o2_1,o2_2,b1,1  
o2,o2_1,o2_2,b2,1  
o2,o2_1,o2_2,b3,2  
o3,o3_1,o3_2,c1,1
```

I tried the following command in awk and it works fine. How can I do the same efficiently in R?

```
awk -F\| '{for (i = 2;i<=NF;i++) print $1","$i}'
```

Comment: You could do a `system` call to that exact `awk` command you wrote. It might be faster than looping in R. Does that count?

Comment: As a benchmark, how long does `awk` take on your 2GB file?

Comment: Thanks flodel. How can I do a system call to that awk command? Can you share the syntax for the same?

Comment: Yes Ananda, there are no quotes. @jilhoward awk took approx 1 min

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty terrible, but maybe you can use something in it.

```
yourData <- scan("yourData.txt", what="character")
makeData <- function(x){
  l <- sapply(x, strsplit, split="[|]")[[1]]
  if(length(l) == 2)
    return(paste(l[1], collapse=","))
  else
    return(unlist(strsplit(paste(l[1], c(l[2:length(l)]), sep=","), split=" ")))
}

( unlist(sapply(yourData, makeData, USE.NAMES=FALSE)) )
## [1] "o1,o1_1,o1_2"      "o2,o2_1,o2_2,b1,1" "o2,o2_1,o2_2,b2,1" "o2,o2_1,o2_2,b3,2" "o3,o3_1,o3_2"
```

If it were me, I would probably just wrap it in a system call, and use the argument intern=TRUE to store the results in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `stri_split` from `stringi` (would be faster)

```
library(stringi)
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
v1 <- scan('Ankitdat.txt', what='', quiet=TRUE)
lst <-  stri_split_regex(v1, '[|]')
setkey(setDT(melt(lst)), L1)[,
     list(paste(value[1], value[-1], sep=',')) ,by=L1][,L1:=NULL][]
#                 V1
#1: o1,o1_1,o1_2,a1,1
#2: o2,o2_1,o2_2,b1,1
#3: o2,o2_1,o2_2,b2,1
#4: o2,o2_1,o2_2,b3,2
#5: o3,o3_1,o3_2,c1,1
```

Or

```
 unlist(sapply(lst, function(x) paste(x[1], x[-1], sep=",")), use.names=FALSE)
 #[1] "o1,o1_1,o1_2,a1,1" "o2,o2_1,o2_2,b1,1" "o2,o2_1,o2_2,b2,1"
 #[4] "o2,o2_1,o2_2,b3,2" "o3,o3_1,o3_2,c1,1"
```